# Jmeter - Capturing pop ups and Images

Tags: jmeter

Is there anyway to capture Pop-ups and Images (for ex: Image Printig) while creating a script on a dot net web page with Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HTTP proxy recorder, those things will be captured along with the rest.